# Flutter web view forms not working properly

Tags: android, forms, flutter, webview

I am using flutter web view for loading a form to the application. But the dropdown menus, date pickers and file selectors not working properly.

Comment: You could add images of the error or complement your question more. It would also be nice if you added what webview package you are using since in https://pub.dev/ there are several packages for this functionality.

Comment: can you share more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which is a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews.

Dropdown menus are working, also date pickers and file selectors (for example, you can use also camera to get images)!